# Angular Grocery List - Delete Single Item

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular app I am trying to get working correctly. Apparently there is just one more line of code that will make it work but I don't know what it is. I am still learning Angular and I'm not that good at Javascript anyway. I've made it so that anything entered into the input gets added to the list. But when I click a button to delete an item, it just deletes all of them. What can I do to fix it?

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="GroceryController">
            <header>
                <h1>Matt's Grocery List</h1>

                <div>
                    <form ng-submit="addItem()">
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="newItem" placeholder="New things">
                            <button type="submit">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </header>
            <section id="list">
            <p>"{{ newItem }}"</p>

            <div>
                <h4>{{ groceries.length }} total items</h4>
                <table>
                    <tr ng-repeat="gro in groceries">
                        <td>{{gro}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="remove" ng-click="removeItem(gro)">&times;</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('GroceryController', function($scope){

    $scope.groceries = ['Nails', 'Pipe', 'Wood'];

    $scope.addItem = function() {
        $scope.groceries.push($scope.newItem);
        $scope.newItem = '';
    }

    $scope.removeItem = function(item) {
        var idx = $scope.groceries.indexOf(item);
            $scope.groceries.splice(idx.l);
    }
});
```

I have a JSfiddle here but I can't actually get it to run in there. It runs just fine when I try to do it in the browser. Maybe you can get it  to run and then you can figure out the problem. I'd really appreciate it! Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/bt08rbqt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your splice method. Use it as below-

```
$scope.removeItem = function(item) {
    $scope.groceries.splice($scope.groceries.indexOf(item),1);
}
```

Comment: You can also use it your way replacing dot (.) with comma (,) after idx variable inside splice method

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it! You're awesome!

Comment: You are welcome. Also,  here is your updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bt08rbqt/1/). Your script was being loaded before angular library. Load type has been changed to No wrap - in <head> from onLoad